# Elasticsearch stem_override filter with big inline list of rules

Tags: elasticsearch, stemming

I wand to add big inline list of rules for stem_override filter (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/analysis-stemmer-override-tokenfilter.html).

My index settings looks like this:

```
{
"settings": {
    "analysis" : {
        "analyzer" : {
            "my_analyzer" : {
                "tokenizer" : "standard",
                "filter" : ["lowercase", "custom_stems", "porter_stem"]
            }
        },
        "filter" : {
            "custom_stems" : {
                "type" : "stemmer_override",
                "rules" : [
                    "running => run",
                    "stemmer => stemmer"
                    ... //200 000 rules
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I send this request to ES it runs so long that I don't receive any response and no index eventually created.
There is solution with rules stored in file in ES config folder. Then filter configuration is:

```
"filter" : {
            "custom_stems" : {
                "type" : "stemmer_override",
                "rules_path" : "analysis/stemmer_override.txt"
            }
        }
```

In this case everything works fine. But this is not what I need. I will not have access to ES filesystem. I need to have possibility create new settings only via request.
Are there any solutions how to make ES process such huge requests(around 4Mb) quickly?

Thanks